# AngularJS $http.get Parameter

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a simple code here and got stuck in passing the parameter. Here is the code:

**route.js**

```
function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/edit/:id', {
        controller: 'UpdateTodoCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/edit-todo.html'
    });
}
```

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="SomeOtherCtrl">
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="t in todos">
<a href="#/edit/{{ t.id }}">{{ t.name }}</a>
</tr>
</table>
</div
```

**Controller**

```
function UpdateTodoCtrl($http, $scope) {

    function init() {
        $scope.todos = null;
        $scope.loading = true;

        $http.get('app/endpoints/edit-todo.php', {
            params: { todoId:  //how to get the id paramter }
        });
    }

}
```

As you can ee in the `controller`, I commented out the part of my problem. How can I possibly pass the id in my url using `$http.get`? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `:id` is a route parameter so you can do like this :

```
function UpdateTodoCtrl($http, $scope, $routeParams) {

    function init() {
        $scope.todos = null;
        $scope.loading = true;

        $http.get('app/endpoints/edit-todo.php', {
            params: { todoId: $routeParams.id }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh my God I forget about this. Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem ;)